# Android remove shadow on password Toggle

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi I want to remove password when I click on display password :passwordToggle

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/et_pass"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_password"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_entry_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_light"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/text_dp_40"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomEditTextTheme" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

When I click to icon display password I see a shadow how I can remove it ?

Comment: hello, could you please post the following drawables to see the error while trying it on android studio? blue_light, CustomEditTextTheme?

Comment: It's not clear which shadow you mean; can you show some image